# Export data and schema only, independent of user in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres database (9.3.4) on a Ubuntu 14.04 server.

What I'd like to do is export it so that I don't have to do a massive find&replace query on the file to change the username from our production system (`deployer`) to my local user (`jrg`).

Is this possible? I need the schema *and* the data.

These are the extensions that are in use:

```
  Name   | Version |   Schema   |                   Description                    
---------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------------
 hstore  | 1.2     | public     | data type for storing sets of (key, value) pairs
 plpgsql | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
```

Comment: So you want a way to remap one or more user names / role names on dump or on restore? Some kind of `pg_dump --remap-user fred=bob` ?

Comment: @CraigRinger or a query to set it so that the user running the pg_restore becomes the owner, so it can be restored by anyone.